# I was solving some Parity Question then, I came across that is magnetic field is parity invariant?

Tags: electromagnetism, parity, magnetostatics

Magnetic field is given by Biot-Savart's Law :
$$\vec{dB} = \frac{\mu_o}{4\pi}\int \frac{I (\vec{dl}\times \hat r)}{r^2}$$
If $P$ denotes the Parity Operator then :
$$P :B\to \,\,\, ?$$

Comment: Well what did you try? Do you know the parity of each object in the integral?

Comment: I know when some quantity is a function of position then parity is non-invariant.

Comment: Ok so what are the parities of $d\ell$, $\hat{r}$ and $r^2$?